# Directory of java is running on my mac (high seirra)

Tags: java, macos, macos-high-sierra

I was running SQL workbench on my mac, and it is complaining that it needs java 8, but instead it found java 10.0.1 on my computer. So I need to locate the java executable and find ways to downgrade the java version. However, I got totally lost when I was looking for the java version.

When I run '/usr/libexec/java_home -V' from terminal, I get this:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
9.0.4, x86_64:  "Java SE 9.0.4" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
```

When I run 'java -version', I get below, which means that it is pointing to the java 9.0.4 listed above:

```
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

However, when I check java control panel under 'System Preferences', it shows that my current java version is 10.0.1 under the tab 'General'. Under tab 'Desktop Settings', the listed JRE path is '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java'. So, it looks like the software (SQL workbench) is complaining about this java version. But how come it is not the java version I got from terminal (9.0.4)? Which java is actually running on my Mac in this case? If I want to change the java 10 listed under java control panel, what should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is not programming-related. It might be better suitable for [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: You should consider asking this on [apple.se].